# Identify unknown SMD component code A6530 72130

Tags: surface-mount, code

I have a TTL to RS485 driver board and I am try identify one of the manufacturer part number from the board.
Can anyone identify the SMD Code and manufacturer part number of the following device?

Code A6530 72130
dimension is 6.6mm x 4mm[image]

[image]

Comment: That's weird.  The package looks derived from current technology for ICs but the reference designator F1 hints at a fuse or maybe a filter.  Also it looks like maybe it was soldered wrong, shifted one pad out of position, though given that the PCB seems to have one larger area rather than match the package pads that may not matter.  What is your goal in identifying it?

Comment: That's true, it is confusing. I am trying to get schematic out of it. Try to get overall cost of making it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"F1" indicates some kind of fuse, and that "B" is the [Bourns](https://www.bourns.com/) logo. Googling "Bourns A6530" leads to the [TBU-CA datasheet](https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/TBU-CA.pdf), which says:

> The TBU-CA Series of Bourns® TBU®
>   products are low capacitance single
>   bidirectional high-speed protection
>   components, constructed using MOSFET
>   semiconductor technology, and designed
>   to protect against faults caused by short
>   circuits, AC power cross, induction and lightning surges.
>
> […]
>
> [image: Bourns TBU-CA marking]

Comment: Great job!  But it would be good to get a brief description into the body of your answer so as not to rely on the link.  The fact that it is MOSFET based makes its physical resemblance to an IC package a little less surprising.

Comment: Looking at how you could determine the company name  based on the logo, is there a list somewhere on the internet which lists common IC logos found in the wild?

Comment: @TejasKale https://www.google.com/search?q=ic+logo+list But I didn't use a list, or knew that "B"; I just guessed that this chip didn't look like a cheap Chinese jellybean part, and the first big fuse manufacturer with a name beginning with "B" that came to mind was Bourns.